# Perform string replace with select query creating new field mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm using the following sql query to select data from my database

```
SELECT * FROM songs_test WHERE id IN ($ids) ORDER BY duration DESC
```

One of the fields being selected is a field called duration. I would like to modify the query to perform a string replace on duration replacing : with nothing and returning it under a new name, such a duration_modified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT *, REPLACE(duration,':', '') as duration_modified FROM songs_test WHERE id IN ($ids) ORDER BY duration DESC;
```

Answer (score 2):

you can do this:

```
SELECT REPLACE(duration, ':', '') as duration_modified, other, names FROM songs_test WHERE id IN ($ids) ORDER BY duration DESC
```